# How to enable/disable scoll view overscrolling?

Tags: android, layout, scroll, scrollview

I am using a scroll view to display some data on the screen. The sroll view properties are wrap content fro layout height and fill parent for layout width. But my scroll view keeps on scrolling even when there is no content on the screen. how do i prevent this overscrolling ?

In general, is there any property to make enable/disable scrollview overscrolling? Everyone wants the iPhone bounce effect when you are scrolling. How to achieve this ?

Comment: This is weird. can you please post a screenshot and the XML here?

Comment: What adapter do you use? What does your `getView()` method do?

Comment: @Peter Knego: i am using a scroll view, where does the adapter get into picture?

Comment: I think there is a problem with another view which is inside the scrollview.. i mean in scrollview if there is linearlayout then check the orientation property.. may be it is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

check this method [ScrollView.setOverScrollMode (int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29)